# Calculate this integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I am having trouble calculating this integral.

Let $1<p<q<\infty$ and $a,b\geq 0$. Calculate:

$$ \int_{0}^{x} \frac{a}{(1+bt^{\frac{q}{p-1}})^\frac{q}{q-p}}dt $$

It would take 'a' out of the integral. But she wouldn't know how to go on. Could you help me?

Comment: You can get rid of both $a$ and $b$ (rescale the variable). Then this smells the incomplete Beta integral.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't figure out how to get the variable 'b'. It only occurs to me to take it out as a common factor, but then I would still have the 1 / b inside. Could you give me another hint?

Comment: I said to rescale $t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

Given $0\le a,0\le b,1<p<q,0<x$, we have $0<\frac{q}{p-1}\land0<\frac{q}{q-p}$. Then,

$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{x}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{a}{\left(1+bt^{\frac{q}{p-1}}\right)^{\frac{q}{q-p}}}
&=\int_{0}^{x^{\frac{q}{p-1}}}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{a\left(\frac{p-1}{q}\right)u^{\frac{p-1}{q}-1}}{\left(1+bu\right)^{\frac{q}{q-p}}};~~~\small{\left[t^{\frac{q}{p-1}}=u\right]}\\
&=a\mu\int_{0}^{x^{1/\mu}}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{u^{\mu-1}}{\left(1+bu\right)^{\nu}};~~~\small{\left[\mu:=\frac{p-1}{q}\land\nu:=\frac{q}{q-p}\right]}\\
&=a\mu\int_{0}^{y}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{u^{\mu-1}}{\left(1+bu\right)^{\nu}};~~~\small{\left[y:=x^{1/\mu}>0\right]}\\
&=a\mu\,y^{\mu}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{t^{\mu-1}}{\left(1+byt\right)^{\nu}};~~~\small{\left[u=yt\right]}\\
&=a\mu\,y^{\mu}\operatorname{B}{\left(\mu,1\right)}\,{_2F_1}{\left(\nu,\mu;\mu+1;-by\right)}\\
&=ay^{\mu}\,{_2F_1}{\left(\nu,\mu;\mu+1;-by\right)}\\
&=ax\,{_2F_1}{\left(\frac{q}{q-p},\frac{p-1}{q};\frac{p+q-1}{q};-bx^{\frac{q}{p-1}}\right)},\\
\end{align}$$

where we've employed Euler's integral representation for the Gauss hypergeometric function which states

$$\operatorname{B}{\left(\beta,\gamma-\beta\right)}\,{_2F_1}{\left(\alpha,\beta;\gamma;z\right)}=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{t^{\beta-1}\left(1-t\right)^{\gamma-\beta-1}}{\left(1-zt\right)^{\alpha}};~~~\small{\left(\alpha,\beta,\gamma,z\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{4}\land0<\beta<\gamma\land z<1}.$$

---

Answer (score 1):

For the time being, forget the $a$ and let $$\alpha=\frac{q}{p-1}\qquad \text{and}\qquad \beta=\frac{q}{q-p}$$ and consider the problem of
$$I=\int \frac{dt}{(1+b~ t^\alpha)^\beta}$$
$$b~ t^\alpha=u \implies t=b^{-\frac{1}{\alpha } }\,u^{\frac{1}{\alpha }}\implies dt=\frac{b^{-\frac{1}{\alpha } }}{\alpha } \,u^{\frac{1}{\alpha }-1}\,du$$
$$I=\frac{b^{-\frac{1}{\alpha } }}{\alpha } \int u^{\frac{1}{\alpha }-1} (u+1)^{-\beta }\,du=\left(\frac{u}{b}\right)^{\frac{1}{\alpha }} \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{\alpha },\beta ;1+\frac{1}{\alpha
   };-u\right)$$